# How to re-aquire video from mavic pro using DJI Mobile SDK?

Tags: swift, swift3, dji-sdk

I have successfully used the Mobile SDK to stream video from the DJI aircraft. However, if I keep the aircraft flying for a long time, the mobile app suddenly can not receive video from the aircraft.

An error has not occurred, so I did not change the code. I tried to restart drone, controller, and the app instead.
After reinstalling the app, the app can receive videos from the aircraft again. However, I want to know how to reacquire video without reinstalling.

The code for acquiring the aircraft video is as follows.

```swift
func setupVideoPreviewer() {
        DJIVideoPreviewer.instance().setView(self.fpvView)
        let product = DJISDKManager.product();
        if ((product?.model == DJIAircraftModelNameA3)
            || (product?.model == DJIAircraftModelNameN3)
            || (product?.model == DJIAircraftModelNameMatrice600)
            || (product?.model == DJIAircraftModelNameMatrice600Pro)){
            // DJISDKManager.videoFeeder()?.secondaryVideoFeed.add(self, with: nil)
            DJISDKManager.videoFeeder()?.primaryVideoFeed.add(self, with: nil)
        }else{
            DJISDKManager.videoFeeder()?.primaryVideoFeed.add(self, with: nil)
        }

        DJIVideoPreviewer.instance().start()
    }
func resetVideoPreview() {
        DJIVideoPreviewer.instance().unSetView()
        let product = DJISDKManager.product();
        if ((product?.model == DJIAircraftModelNameA3)
            || (product?.model == DJIAircraftModelNameN3)
            || (product?.model == DJIAircraftModelNameMatrice600)
            || (product?.model == DJIAircraftModelNameMatrice600Pro)){
            // DJISDKManager.videoFeeder()?.secondaryVideoFeed.remove(self)
            DJISDKManager.videoFeeder()?.primaryVideoFeed.remove(self)
        }else{
            DJISDKManager.videoFeeder()?.primaryVideoFeed.remove(self)
        }
    }
```

```swift
func videoFeed(_ videoFeed: DJIVideoFeed, didUpdateVideoData rawData: Data) {
        let videoData = rawData as NSData
        let videoBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: videoData.length)
        videoData.getBytes(videoBuffer, length: videoData.length)
        videoix += 1
        DJIVideoPreviewer.instance().push(videoBuffer, length: Int32(videoData.length))
        //videoBuffer.deallocate(capacity: videoData.length)
    }
```

Comment: we use custom PSDK to stream down for hours without issue. Guess you might have a possible memory leak in your code. One way to quick check is to (1) use GO app and see if the stream from Go app also freese. if fieeze, try another phone. to rule out the specific phone problem.  If Go app not freeze, then high chance its your code that have issue

Comment: also forgot to mention, there are some times video break. but as long as the source is streaming, it will get back on automatically.

Comment: OK. thank you. I think my code have memory leak problem.

Comment: Did you ever fix this?